# Le verbe « imposer » employé de façon absolue

Tags: grammaire, usage, infinitif, transitivité

J'aurais besoin de vos lumières pour éclaircir la question suivante : est-ce qu'on peut utiliser le verbe « imposer » sans complément, comme dans la phrase suivante : 
« Arrête d'imposer ! » avec comme complément d'objet sous-entendu « des choses ( que j'ai pas envie de faire) » ?

Answer (score 2):

Oui! On peut absolument. Je ne connais pas de verbe français que l'on ne puisse utiliser dans le cadre d'une complétive infinitive non elle-même complémentée et ce **dans l'intention de rendre une idée générale.**

Cela peut sembler effectivement plus naturel avec des verbes dits intransitifs qu'avec des verbes transitifs pour lesquels l'objet précis de l'action **peut** être précisé. Mais... la transitivité n'interdit rien... et en particulier pas de l'ignorer.

En fonction de la nature de ce qui est effectivement *imposé* (abstrait / concret), on pourra toutefois préférer ***exiger*** ou ***commander*** voire ***ordonner*** à ***imposer*** mais ce sera plus une affaire de contexte, de nuances ou de style.
Ainsi j'*impose* plus facilement des idées, mais *exige* plus volontiers des choses.

Answer (score 0):

Il me semble que la réponse n'est ni oui ni non dans le cas général, c'est à dire quel que soit le verbe. Selon le contexte c'est un usage qui est plus ou moins naturel ou qui ne l'est pas.

- Une personne en accompagnant une autre dans un supermarché alors que cette dernière passe au crible les articles en quête de signes de mauvaise qualité, ne dira pas naturellement « Arrête d'examiner ! ». On s'attend à un complément : « Arrête de tout examiner ! », « Arrête d'examiner (tout) ce que tu vas acheter ! »,…
- Une personne dans une bibliothèque cherchant à se servir d'un ouvrage de référence utilisé par une autre pourra dire à celle-ci « Est-ce que je peux consulter ? », mais il semble préférable de préserver un complément :  « Est-ce que je peux consulter ce dictionnaire ? », « Est-ce que je peux le consulter ? »,…

On s'aperçoit, dit en passant, qu'il existe une forte tendance chez les immigrants ayant encore mal assimilé la langue, à utiliser les verbes transitifs sans complément, mais il ne faut tirer aucune conclusion hâtive de ce phénomène.

Pour montrer que l'on est confronté à un usage disparate, considérons le verbe « spéculer », verbe transitif indirect. Le TLFi dit ceci :

> « [Le compl. d'obj. indir. peut ne pas être exprimé] ».

Dans une conversation où l'un des participants est engagé sur la voie de faire de nombreuses prévisions à base d'aussi nombreuses hypothèses, on ne sera pas surpris d'entendre « Arrête de spéculer ! », cela  parce qu'il existe un usage assez bien établi.

Ce principe est encore vrai pour « inventer » auquel le TLFi reconnait un emploi absolu.

> Absol. Il [Pierre le fou] inventait à mesure;

- Arrête d'inventer ! Je n'ai jamais dit ça. (*tout à fait naturel*)

Prenons un tout autre cas maintenant, avec le verbe « commencer ».

- Une personne voulant savoir pourquoi le travail qu'elle a demandé à quelqu'un n'est pas fait et s'entendant dire que la raison est qu'il a fallu en commencer d'autres et que de nouveaux travaux sont commencés avant de pouvoir en  finir aucun, ne pourra pas dire naturellement « Mais arrêtez de commencer ! », sauf avec une sorte d'ironie (que je ne sais moi-même comment rendre certaine) ; il n'existe pas réellement d'usage courant, on s'attend à ce qu'un complément soit formulé.

On peut remarquer que ce sens du verbe ne correspond à aucun de ceux pour lesquels il existe la possibilité d'un emploi absolu (TLFi).

> 4. Emploi abs.
>      a) [Le compl. d'obj. implicite est un verbe ou un subst. d'action ou un terme suggéré par le cont.]

Un seul complément d'objet implicite est sous entendu dans l'usage absolu auquel il est référé dans « a) ».

En conclusion, comme il n'y a aucun usage absolu reconnu pour le verbe « imposer », non, ce n'est pas possible de l'utiliser ainsi, mais vu l'existence d'une tendance qu'on les verbes à acquérir cet usage, le locuteur peut plus impunément enfreindre l'usage strict et contribuer à un nouvel usage s'il le trouve justifié.

Answer (score -1):

La réponse à votre question est non : dire à quelqu'un "Arrête d'imposer" est au pire impropre, au mieux incompréhensible. Si cette personne veut vous imposer quelque chose contre votre gré, vous pouvez lui dire "Tu n'as pas à imposer ton point de vue", "Tu n'es pas autorisé à imposer ton point de vue", "Je ne vois pas pourquoi ton avis prévaudrait". Toutefois vous pourriez dire "Arrête de t'imposer" si, à plusieurs reprises, votre interlocuteur a essayé d'imposer son point de vue. Si vous dites "arrête d'imposer", on se demande ce que vous pouvez bien vouloir dire, en particulier on est fondé à se demander "arrête d'imposer quoi ?"